# How to use threading or Task pattern in following scenario

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two methods using in Main method like this

```
public bool isBadMethod() 
{ 
   bool isBad = Method1();
   if(isBad) return true; 
   else return Method2(); 
}

bool Method1() { ..... return true or false }         
bool Method2() { ..... return true or false }
```

If any of Method1 or Method2 returning true no need to check for other method we can return MainMethod as true. But if first method returns false then need to check for second method and finally return  whatever second method returns. Here Method1 and Method2 are time consuming methods. Can I use asynchronous programming on these methods. Help how to do. (I'm using .net 4.0)

Comment: In theory you could start both going in separate tasks. Then if Method1() returns true, cancel Method2(); otherwise wait for Method2() to complete. This relies on the fact that you can cancel Method2()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just make use of short-circuiting of expressions:

```
bool val = Method1() || Method2();
```

If `Method1` returns `true`, it doesn't bother with the second method.

Obviously, if the method calls are expensive then continue with the task route, as this isn't parallel execution. I'm just posting this in case it's an XY Problem.

---

Using tasks, this might be something like what you want. It will run both methods and then just use an expression to grab the right result. In this instance it waits the full 3 seconds to grab the result of `Method2`. This also does cancellation. I am not sure if the types used are best practice as my experience with this is patchy, but it gets the job done in my sandbox:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cm2 = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var m1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Method1());
        var m2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Method2(cm2.Token), cm2.Token);

        var val = m1.Result || m2.Result;

        cm2.Cancel();

        Console.WriteLine(val);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static bool Method1()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine(1);
        return true;
    }

    private static bool Method2(CancellationToken token)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            return false;

        Console.WriteLine(2);
        return true;
    }
}
```

As Matthew Watson points out in the comments, the cancellation token needs to be used by `Method2` in order to actually "cancel". In my example, it simply stops the printing of the number and returns early.

Comment: Very similar to my answer - but I typed too slowly. :) I'd just like to point out that the cancellation token has to be actually used inside the task method, otherwise it won't do anything.

Comment: The `cm1.Cancel();` seems unnecessary, it's still left-to-right eval.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes true, I didn't see that because of my contrived example making the left faster than the right (oh to live in a simpler world). Changed it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Fair catch, I'll make a note of it.

Comment: [Sample usage of cancellation token here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks for that. This question met my goal of actually teaching me something again about TPL. SO is a good litmus test about how much you actually know of a topic. I've started answering them in the hopes of gleaming tidbits out.

Comment: Thanks Adam for your answer. In my scenario main problem is not sure which method is faster? I tested my code in almost 10 - 15 times with different cases. In that almost 95% times Method1 is taking less time but 5% of times Method2 is executing first. Can we implement Cancellationtoken in such a way that if Method2 returns True It will stop execution of Method1 and Vice versa?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care if Method2() keeps running after Method1() has returned, it's not hard to do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private void run()
        {
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            bool result = test();
            Console.WriteLine("Returned " + result + " after " + sw.Elapsed);
        }

        private bool test()
        {
            var method1 = Task.Run(new Func<bool>(Method1));
            var method2 = Task.Run(new Func<bool>(Method2));

            return method1.Result || method2.Result;
        }

        public bool Method1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Method1()");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("Returning from Method1()");
            return true;
        }

        public bool Method2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Method2()");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("Returning true from Method2()");
            return true;
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

Method1() takes 2 seconds to complete.
Method1() takes 3 seconds to complete.

When you run this with Method1() set to return true, the total time is around 2 seconds - which is the running time of Method1().

If you edit Method1() so that it returns false, the total time is around 3 seconds - the running time of Method2().

So you can see that it is not running both tasks sequentially. This approach is a form of "speculative execution".

However, if you must cancel Method2() when Method1() returns true, it gets more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Using Tasks, your logic could be performed like this:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory                     
    .StartNew<bool>(        
        () => {  return Method1(); })        
    .ContinueWith<bool>(prev =>        
        {                        
            if (!prev.Result)                                
                return Method2();
            else
                return true;         
        })
    .ContinueWith(prev =>        
        {                        
            // do something with prev.Result
        })
```

Note that you could perform the logic from the third Task in the second one or even perform all in just one Task, it depends on your requirements. For instance, you may need the third task to be synchronized with your UI.